# I can't find out how to replay my game when the player wins or loses

Tags: python

I can't find out how to replay my game when the player wins or loses

```
import math
import random
list = ['rock','paper','scissors']
winstreek = 0

player = input("rock paper or scissors?")
computer = random.choice(list)

if player == "rock":
  if computer == "rock":
    print("tie")
  if computer == "paper":
    print("computer wins")
  if computer == "scissors":
    print("player wins")
    winstreek += 1

if player == "paper":
  if computer == "rock":
    print("player wins")
    winstreek += 1
  if computer == "paper":
    print("tie")
  if computer == "scissors":
    print("computer wins")

if player == "scissors":
  if computer == "rock":
    print("computer wins")
  if computer == "paper":
    print("player wins")
    winstreek += 1
  if computer == "scissors":
    print("tie")

print(" ")
print(f"winstreek: {winstreek}")
```

Comment: Seems like you're an absolute beginner; I suggest reading the section "An Informal Introduction to Python" on the Python website. Specifically, the [3.2. First Steps Towards Programming](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming) section introduces the concept of a "`while`" loop, which will help you here. In addition to allowing you to start the game over again, you can also use a "nested loop" to reduce the number of `if` statements in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the play run in a loop, eg

```
player = ''
while player != 'quit':
  #your playing code indented into this while loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a while loop:

```
import math
import random

i = "5"
while i == "5":
  list = ['rock','paper','scissors']
  winstreek = 0
  
  player = input("rock paper or scissors?")
  computer = random.choice(list)
  
  if player == "rock":
    if computer == "rock":
      print("tie")
    if computer == "paper":
      print("computer wins")
    if computer == "scissors":
      print("player wins")
      winstreek += 1
  
  if player == "paper":
    if computer == "rock":
      print("player wins")
      winstreek += 1
    if computer == "paper":
      print("tie")
    if computer == "scissors":
      print("computer wins")
  
  if player == "scissors":
    if computer == "rock":
      print("computer wins")
  if computer == "paper":
    print("player wins")
    winstreek += 1
  if computer == "scissors":
    print("tie")
```

Just copy and paste.